# Best practices for forgot password function via REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, restful-authentication

I am trying to find the best practices for forgot password functionality via  sending a link to reset password i.e. sending an email with a one time token to the registered user. The token will be stored in the database and when the user clicks the link, we check the token and allow the user to set a new password.

Best practices while designing forgot password function -

- The token must be unpredictable, that's accomplished best with a
  "really" random code which is not based upon a timestamp or values
  like the user-id.
- Like a password, the token should be hashed, before    storing it in
  the database. This makes them useless for an attacker,    even if the
  database is stolen.
- The reset-link should preferably be    short to avoid problems with
  email clients, and contain only safe    characters 0-9 A-Z a-z
  (base62 encoded)
- The token should have an expiration time within single-digit hours.
- The token should be marked as used,after the user has
  successfully set a new password.
- When a user changes their password or requests another password
  reset, expire all tokens already associated with their account.

These are some of the points I found. What can be other security issues that should be considered ?

Sources:
[Secure password-reset function](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset)
[Ycombinator News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5033513)

Answer (score 1):

A couple other practices I've seen:

- Check user is on the same machine/browser/IP as the one where the reset password request was triggered (unless it was initiated by admin/system).
- Rate-limit number of reset tokens that can be generated for an account.

It should also be noted that the best practice is usually to use an established library rather than inventing your own mechanism, as too many things can be overlooked.

Comment: +1 for using an established library. The people who live and breathe security make mistakes. If you don't, yours will be worse, and you'll have a smaller set of white hats to find them.

Comment: Can u suggest any library to use with python-social-auth and Django Rest framework ?

Comment: There seems to be this https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth but I don't know Python/Django well enough to say it's the best. You could try asking on slant.co or elsewhere (since "what's the best X" is sadly off-topic for SO).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question and found the [OWASP Forgot Password Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet).
Also few things that I would like to add:

1. Usually if user entered non existing email sites anyway shows message "pwd restoration link was sent". This is due to prevent hackers from determining that user with the email exists in system. But IMHO it's better to say user that email is not exists because usually it may not remember email used during registration.
2. It is better to add some additional personal question to user like a birthday date. If hacker stole user's email it makes harder to receive reset link. But since reset link may be sent to user by site admin the question with birthday must be on change password page which is opened by link.
3. Hackers may automatically send a lot of letters to some user. Some sites uses a CAPTCHA near email field to prevent this.
4. After successful changing of password all active sessions should be closed and user must be logged out. Thus even if hacker is logged in he will logged out.
5. It is a good idea to hash a restoration ticket like a password. Here should be used the same [hashing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) like with password: Argon2, SCrypt, BCrypt.
6. After user restoration password it is good to mark it a possible fraud and for some time (like a week) do not allow to make some critical actions, like withdrawal money from account.
7. Also some sites are sending a letter to user that it's password was changed. They do this when user was logged normally changed it manually but maybe it is good to send the same latter when pwd was reseted.